# Converting Column Array to Rows Array in Flex

Tags: arrays, algorithm, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Im trying to make a multidimensional array to save the data but I obtain an error ("TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.").

```
var cols:int = sheet.cols;
var rows:int = sheet.values.length;
var ridx:int = 0;
var cidx:int = 0;
var out:Array = new Array();

var i:int;
for (i=0; i < cols; i++) {
    out[i] = new Array();
    var j:int;

    for (j=0; j < rows; j++) {
        out[ridx][cidx] = sheet.getCell(j, i).value;

        ridx++;

        if(ridx >= rows) {
            cidx++;
            ridx = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Now I have this code:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    out[i] = new Array();                   
    for (var j:int = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        out[j][i] = sheet.getCell(j, i).value; //IM GETTING THE ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have two pairs of variables (i,j) and (ridx,cidx) doing the exact same job: indexing the rows and columns of your Array and Sheet.  Get rid of one of them.

Comment: I did that but doesnt works, im getting the same error.

Comment: Which line triggers the error?  Offhand, it could be anything from `sheet.cols` down to part of `out[ridx][cidx] = sheet.getCell(j, i).value;`  I'd suggest breaking that up with statements like `var currentCell:* = sheet.getCell(j, i);` and `var outR:Array = out[ridx];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign a cell value to a nonexistent location in your output array.

In the first `i` loop, you assign `out[0] = new Array();`, then in the `j` loop, you'll set `out[0][0] = sheet.getCell(0,0).value;`
In the second `j` loop, you'll set `out[1][0] = sheet.getCell(1,0).value;`

In this case, `sheet.getCell(1,0)` may return `null`, but whether it does or not, `out[1]` is null, so your code translates to `null[0] = ...` -- which will trigger the error you're seeing.

You can probably fix this by swapping `i` and `j` in your inner loop.

Comment: But my problem right now is to transform the column array to row array: http://puu.sh/gPzQM/e8ad38b115.png i need to get the array like this: http://puu.sh/gPA4m/f8116d0e7e.png